# login page application using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have designed a login page application in Angular js.  but I need a help in the browser when I click back button it again navigating to home page or login page for to stop back button work what should we do.

when I click back button in browser it should not navigate to home page or login page.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376568/back-button-behavior-in-angular-js-application/30377293#30377293

Answer (score 1):

Please see working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/46O0znC5HFDE4cYXSm5h?p=preview

Stored data in cookies in login function as follows,

```
$cookies.userinfo = {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'pqr'
};
```

And on logout remove that data -

```
delete $cookies.userinfo;
```

then check for 'angular.isDefined($cookies.userinfo)' (userinfo is cookie name which given at the time of storing data in it) if find then redirect it to your page which you want to see after login. i.e

```
app.run(function ($cookies) {
      $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function () {
        if (angular.isDefined($cookies.userinfo)) {
            $location.path("/pathname");
        }

      });
});
```