# back button behavior in angular js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I have an issue with a SPA app written in angularJS. The application consist of thre views - login view, main view and log out view.

- myapp/#/login
- myapp/#/main
- myapp/#/logout

my route provider:

```
function Router($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'login.ctrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/main', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/dashboard/main.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'dashboard.ctrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/logout', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/logout/logout.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'logout.ctrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
}
```

Use case:
   1) user logs in. 
   2) user sees the content in the main view
   3) user logs out.
   4) user is redirected to the logout view for confirmation
   5) user is redirected to the login view

If I press the back browser button after step 5 I am redirected to the main view. Is there a way to change the behavior of the back button when I am in the login view? I believe it is something simple and I apologize if the question is duplicated. Thank you for your time and responses!

Comment: You have to use `$window.history.pushState` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Please check this might be help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208454/login-page-application-using-angular-js/30208585#30208585

Comment: @ Avraam do I have to include the  `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` in order to use `$window.history.pushState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/46O0znC5HFDE4cYXSm5h?p=preview

Stored data in cookies in login function as follows,

```
$cookies.userinfo = {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'pqr'
};
```

And on logout remove that data -

```
delete $cookies.userinfo;
```

then check for 'angular.isDefined($cookies.userinfo)' (userinfo is cookie name which given at the time of storing data in it) if find then redirect it to your page which you want to see after login. i.e

```
app.run(function ($cookies) {
      $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function () {
        if (angular.isDefined($cookies.userinfo)) {
            $location.path("/pathname");
        }

      });
});
```

Comment: how can I get the cookie for the specific user :?

Comment: and btw this service is deprecated
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore

Comment: Then use $cookies and apply the same.  For 1st question answer is - Store  user information while user is login(i.e in login controller using put method of cookies) in cookies and use that information in above code.

Comment: here is my suggestion:
function login(user) {
$cookies.put('1', 'userinfo');
}

But for some reason it produces an error.

Comment: Please check I have updated my answer and also created example wor you. Try back button click on plunker I have created.